# How to loop through a list of dictionaries to extract the values

Tags: python, list

I have a list of simple key value pair dictionaries.  I want to return all the values

eg.

```
namelist([ {'name': 'Bart'}, {'name': 'Lisa'}, {'name': 'Maggie'} ])
# returns 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'
```

whats the solution to this?

I do not understand how to do this.  first I have just tried looping through to return each value in the list and it only returns the first item.

```
def namelist(names):
    for i in names:
        return i
```

It only returns:

```
{name: 'Bart'}
```

The end result should return:  'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'

I dont even understand why my loop isnt looping through each item in the list, just the first.

Comment: you have a list and a python hammer, wow!

Comment: `return [i for i in names.values()]`

Answer (score -1):

you're `return`ing which exits the function. Just use `print`